# jQuery UI event and ui object properties

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In the jQuery UI framework for Interactions you can do custom functions and they take two parameters 'event' and 'ui'.  I know it has to be obvious somewhere but I cannot find out what methods and properties are available on those two parameters.

Does someone know what methods and properties are available on those parameters or where I can I find them?

Comment: Do a `console.log(event)` and `console.log(ui)` and read what comes out in Firebug

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The documentation is always a good place to start, for instance the stuff you find in the `ui` object for `draggable` is available here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/. The event object is always the original event that is fired, while the `ui` object contains information added by jQuery UI.

If you want you can also do your own digging. Using `console.log` on Firefox with the Firebug and Firequery add-ons, you can look at the insides of both objects. For instance, with this code:

```
$('#test').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui){
        console.log(event);
        console.log(ui);
    }
});
```

The `ui` object looks like:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize that the event was the base event.  I knew there had to be a way to debug with Firebug but I did not know what it was.  Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

this is a link for the event object http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

for UI object it depends on the UI that you are using check this http://docs.jquery.com/UI/