# Jquery ui Dialogue close event to refresh window

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I need a way to reload my parent page when I close my jqUI modal window.  Somehow or the other, what I am currently doing is not working (imagine that)...

```
$('div#addPat').live('dialogclose', function (event) {
                debugger;
                location.reload(true);
            });
```

I never get to the debugger statement so I assume just assume that my event is wrong...

How do I get the close dialog event and how can I use it to reload the page... I think I have the second part figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $( "div#addPat" ).dialog({
 close: function(event, ui) {
      debugger;
      ....
  }
});
```

REF: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-close

Comment: Thanks... that worked great.  Now however, I don't know if that is the direction I want to go... Reloading the entire page everytime you close the dialogue window seems kind of intrusive.  I may go in another direction... But thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: Are `event` and `ui` ever populated with anything useful?  What if you only wanted to close the window based on what triggered the close? Seems like `ui` is always empty.

Comment: @Snekse, IMHO your question deserves to be a new question by itself. I believe that you could close without `event` or `ui` params and it would work just fine. I have seen this code in API documentation and hence I posted it in my solution. One reason I can think of using those params would be if you wanted to override by calling `event.preventDefault()`. Thanks to you I had never seriously questioned about these arguments. Here are some useful links I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691773/jquery-ui-event-and-ui-object-properties