# Radio buttons not changing how javascript selects elements my table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, razor

**Problem**

How to use radio buttons to control selection behavior by JQuery UI?

Right now, I can select all the green boxes (success) as intended with Check Out. Please note that when I select something it is orange.

My problem is that if I choose Check In, I cannot select any of the blue boxes. Also, I probably need a way to "refresh" when I change radio buttons so the green boxes are not still selected when I want to change radio buttons.

[image]

### Code (view)

I am using JQuery selectable to get the job done. You can read more about it from the api documentation found [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/). I tried to get jquery to "filter" based on whether or not the radio box was checked. Clearly, this approach is failing.

**Edit** I think the approach is failing because it is loading the javascript once? So when I change the radio buttons, my filter definition is not changing.

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Details</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/table.css" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){


            //Have this be a conditional based on radio input
            var getRad1 = document.getElementById('optionsRadios1');
            if (getRad1.checked)
            {
                console.log("Check has passed for Check in");

                $("#selectable").selectable({
                    filter: ".success"
                });

                //getter
                var filter = $(".selector").selectable("option", "filter");
            }

            //option 2
            var getRad2 = document.getElementById('optionsRadios2');
            if (getRad2.checked) {
                //$("#selectable").selectable("refresh");

                console.log("Check has passed for Check in");

                $("#selectable").selectable({
                    filter: ".info"
                });

                //getter
                var filter = $(".selector").selectable("option", "filter");
            }



            //I am not sure what this is doing 
            var select_range = false;

            //queue of objects to deselect 
            var deselect_queue = [];




            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691773/jquery-ui-event-and-ui-object-properties
            $("#selectable").selectable({

                selecting: function(event, ui)
                {
                    var selecting = $(ui.selecting);
                    if (selecting.hasClass('ui-selected')) {
                        deselect_queue.push(selecting);
                    }
                },


                //This is what keeps previous selected items as selected? 
                unselecting: function (event, ui) {
                    $(ui.unselecting).addClass('ui-selected');
                },


                //Triggered at the end of the select operation 
                stop: function () {
                    if (!select_range) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < deselect_queue.length; i++) {
                            deselect_queue[i]
                              .removeClass('ui-selecting')
                                .removeClass('ui-selected')
                        }
                    }
                    select_range = false;
                    deselect_queue = [];

                    //Something else went here that I didn't understand
                }
            });  

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>



        @{ int columnN = Model.columnNumber;}
        @{ int rowN = Model.rowNumber;}
        @{ int index = 1;}
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                @for (int j = 1; j <= columnN; j++)
                {
                    <th>@j.ToString()</th>
                }
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody id="selectable">
            @for (int i = 1; i <= rowN; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>@i.ToString()</th>
                    @for (int k = 1; k <= columnN; k++)
                    {
                        if (k % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            <td  class="book success" data-id=@index> @index.ToString() </td>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <td class="book info" data-id=@index> @index.ToString() </td>
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Legend</legend>        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Radios</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" type="radio" checked="" value="option1">
                            Check out (Depopulate)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" type="radio" value="option2">
                            Check in (populate)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Attempts

- I am trying to use conditionals inside the main javascript function. It works for the initial time and sets everything up and then fails.
- I could have two separate views, but that defeats the purpose of having dynamic page content.

I think I am close with trying to read the dom elements and change my javascript behavior, but I can't quite get it to work right (I might be way off too). I deeply appreciate any assistance that could be rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this solution in hopes that someone else might find this post useful.

### Solution

The radio buttons need a listener. So it is necessary to add onclick="" to them. However, what I need is two functions to have the behavior I seek. Otherwise, the javascript will load and then become useless to us, even with radio buttons.

1. Select only elements are green
2. Select only elements who are blue

Thus, the following functions need to be added to javascript:

```
        function populate() {
               //$("#selectable").selectable("refresh");

                console.log("Check has passed for Check in");
                $(".selector").selectable("refresh");

                $("#selectable").selectable({
                    filter: ".info"
                });

                var filter = $(".selector").selectable("option", "filter", ".info");

        };


        function depopulate() {
            console.log("Check has passed for Check in");
            $(".selector").selectable("refresh");

            $("#selectable").selectable({
                filter: ".success"
            });

            var filter = $(".selector").selectable("option", "filter", ".success");
        };
```

The radio button needs to be  modified as follows:

```
<input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" type="radio" checked="" value="option1" onclick="depopulate()">
<input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" type="radio" value="option2" onclick="populate()">
```

After this, clicking on the radio buttons will give us the behavior we desired.